# What is the purpose of a Dual Degree?

Tags: graduate-school, degree

I'm in Germany studying a Master of Computer Science, and the program has options of Dual Degrees with other Universities from outside of Germany (US, Europe, Asia). I'm thinking of applying to the Dual Degree, but i have doubts about the purpose of getting two degrees.

Is there a defined purpose or career profile for such double degree programs? In what case should I apply or in what case I shouldn't?

Comment: Often a dual-degree serves as a statement of interest to do multi-disciplinary research. A common subject for dual-degree where I study is MEMS or Micro-Electro-Mechanical-Systems and Physics of Integrated Circuits.

Comment: I should point that the other MSc program is Autonomous Systems/Robotics.

Answer (score 4):

I think you should apply if you find both the degrees interesting, and they are complementary. For example, Physics and Computer Science if you aim at writing very good quality physics models (e.g. climate models). Maybe it is hard for you to say what you really want, and therefore it might be hard to judge whether or what dual master (if any) would work for you. On the short term I would try and see if you are drawn towards both masters. If so, you could get a dual degree. Do mind that I suspect two degrees is more work. If you are up to it, and willing to dedicate the time, it could be worth it. On the other hand, I would not recommend just doing it because you feel it might look good on your resume.

Answer (score 1):

*I believe the main questions here are:*

- is the knowledge you will gain from the other degree is of your interest?
- does it will help you to become a better researcher?

If the answer is yes for the both then definitely worth to try it and work hardly to make it.
I found this is useful *specially in Computer Science* (as there are many multi-discipline research areas these days). Some Examples are Computational Biology, Decision Science and of course mathematics.